# Sharepoint xsl ddwrt FormatDateTime issue

Tags: sharepoint, datetime, xslt, date, formatting

I use the ddwrt:FormatDateTime function to format the output like yyyyMMdd.
inputs like 01/01/2010 work fine but when the day gets over the number 12 the output is an emtpy string.

```
ddwrt:FormatDate(string(@myDate), 1033, 'yyyyMMdd')
```

At first I thought it could be a language specific problem but even none of those combinations work:

```
13/01/2010
01/13/2010
13.01.2010
```

Answer (score 3):

I googled and [found out](http://autosponge.spaces.live.com/Blog/cns!D7F85948C20F0293!378.entry) that sharepoint uses ISO8601 format of the date: yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ssZ"

Th same page and the [Microsoft origin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa505323.aspx#officesharepointddwrt_formatdate) state that the third parameter of the function is long and not the formatting string.

Answer (score 1):

In practice, there are two options for the third parameter. One is a long, the other works much as you believed.

The only problem with using the string option is that not all the possible combinations of *yyyy M d* (etc) work. *"dddd MMMM d, yyyy"* works fine, as does *".mm"*; but not *"mm"*. This is a pain, but is better than nothing.